# How can I use imbedded IF statements to include AND/OR to properly solve multiple conditions?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, forex

I have reviewed quite a few previous questions and answers in the forum, but none provide me the solution to solve my calculation needed.

This is a forex trading scenario in Excel where I am calculating movement between prices.

Here is the idea that I am trying to set a calculation for...

If p10="Win" and d10="Long", then ABS(n10-c10)*10000.   This should return a positive number.  If p10="Win" and d10="Short", then (c10-n10)*10000.  This should also return a positive number.

If p10="Loss" and d10="Long", then (n10-c10)*10000. However, this should return a negative number.  Just as if p10="Loss" and d10="Short), then (c10-n10)*10000 should also return a negative number.

I have tried combining IF(OR(AND statements, however, I am still not able to return proper results on all trades.

Would like to see if anyone may be able to see something or suggest a remedy that I may have not considered.

Comment: I don't see where you need the `OR`. I'll try a solution without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. You need to put it into one single line:

```
=IF(AND(P10="Win"; D10="Long"); ABS(N10-C10)*10000; 
    IF(AND(P10="Win"; D10="Short"); (c10-n10)*10000; 
       IF(AND(P10="Loss"; D10="Long");  (n10-c10)*10000; 
          IF(AND(P10="Loss"; D10="Short"); (c10-n10)*10000; 
            )
         )
      )
    )
```

Comment: This in fact is the solution, and I thank you most kindly.  I have copied/pasted throughout my spreadsheet, and all returned correctly. Thank you so much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Great to see it works. Now when your trading business boosts, let me know!

Comment: is there a way to privately communicate with various users?  Would love to keep you posted on how things are progressing.